# How to recreate per-web-request component?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have a component registered Per-Web-Request. How can I force to recreate the component during processing of a request?

`container.Release(obj);` doesn't help(As far as i know, it doesn't work at all for Singleton and PerWebRequest).

Comment: Assuming you could, would you want the lifetime on that second component to also be Per-Web-Request or a different lifetime?

Comment: The second component should by Per-Web-Request too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most extensible solution but if you only need a second component (and not a third, fourth, etc) you can create a new class that inherits from your other one and register it too.

I do feel like it's a weird situation.  If you want to post more context I may be able to add some design advice.